# Why i cant swap my own token on pancakeswap…it says k error

Tags: solidity, tokens

my tokes has 10% tax on transaction. i have add the liquidity but no one can buy my token & i also cant pull out the liquidity.

i have tried to increase slippage percentages and also try to shuffle token amount. nothing is working.

is says transaction reverted due to K error.

Comment: It is very likely there's a bug in the contract.

Comment: i dont think so, can you check my code?

Comment: There are hundred of tokens that work with uniswap/pancakeswap without issues. Add the contract to the question if you want someone to take a look at it.

Comment: ok....can i send it to you? email or any other platform?

Comment: This site is for answering concrete issues, if you can't show the contract then it is unlikely it will be answered here. If you want to hire someone check at gitcoin, linkedin or similar places.